# Alternative to org.easymock.EasyMock.capture in Java 8 to 11

Tags: java, java-8, easymock, type-erasure

I'm trying to capture values in my test

```
...
final Capture<MyDTO> myDTOCaptured = new Capture<MyDTO>();

EasyMock.expect(this.serviceMock.execute(capture(myDTOCaptured)).andReturn(someResult);
...
```

The Documentation says:

**Deprecated API**

> org.easymock.EasyMock.capture(Capture)
>             Because of harder erasure enforcement, doesn't compile in Java 7

http://easymock.sourceforge.net/api/easymock/3.1/deprecated-list.html

Version 3.1 is the version we are using.

Is there any alternative for capture in Java 8+? I guess the alternative is upgrading the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to latest EasyMock (4.2) and use generic method [capture(Capture<T> captured)](https://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/EasyMock.html#capture-org.easymock.Capture-) as a replacement

> Expect any object but captures it for later use

[Example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=org.easymock.Capture):

> ```
> final Capture<TwoWayChannelMessage> initiateCapture = new Capture<>();
> connection.sendToClient(capture(initiateCapture));
> ```

Comment: @PascalPetruch yes, upgrade to latest 4.2

Answer (score 3):

This website is obsolete. The real up-to-date EasyMock website is http://easymock.org/. EasyMock moved out of SourceForge a long time ago.

Latest EasyMock would be

```
Capture<TwoWayChannelMessage> initiateCapture = EasyMock.newCapture();
connection.sendToClient(capture(initiateCapture));
```